# How does SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access determine the clustered and non clustered indexes?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

I am a beginner of SQL Server and Access. I was trying the Migration Assistant to SQL Server for Access and I realized that it automatically creates the clustered and non clustered indexes in the SQL Server database.

However, I do not understand how it is created. I could not find anything that says clustered and nonclustered indexes in my Access database. How did the migration assistant determine how to create indexes?

Comment: Well, the **clustered** index is usually defined on the **primary key** of any given table - and you can created nonclustered indices on anything you like, but one thing that's strongly recommended (for performance) is having nonclustered indices on the foreign key columns of any table - maybe that's what the Migration Assistant uses as guide lines .....

Comment: I believe MS Access actually has indexes so I guess they would be converted into non clustered indexes. As already mentioned, it's a good guess that an MS Access primary key will be converted into a clustered index. It would definitely be converted into a SQL Server Primary key (which may or may not be the clustered index)

Comment: Now I understand the primary key clustered indices. But what I do not understand is how it creates nonclustered indices because the migration wizard does not import table relationships. How does it know which fields are for foreign keys?

Comment: A non-clustered index doesn't have any special relationship to a foreign key relationship.

Comment: If it's automatically generating foreign keys then it's doing it based on your relationships. There's no other way